# FindAll() in Linq Query List

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Linq Query made into a list called "ticket query"
I want to search ticket query for all the records that have specific data

I tried using `FindAll()` but it gives me an error

> Argument matching parameter 'match' cannot convert from 
>       'VB$AnonymousDelegate_1(Of JobPartForm,Nullable(Of Boolean))' to
>       'Predicate(Of JobPartForm)'.

I can't do the findall directly in the query because its being called at a separate time

is there another way to accomplish this, or am I using find all wrong?

```
ticketquery = (From ticket In dbContext.JobPartForm
                       Select ticket).ToList()

Dim formticket = ticketquery.FindAll(Function(f As JobPartForm) f.JobNum = ticketnum And f.FormNumber = formnum)
```

Comment: How is `FindAll()` implemented? Please show its full source.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using [`IQueryable<TSource>.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim formticket=dbContext.JobPartForm.Where((Function(f As JobPartForm) f.JobNum = ticketnum And f.FormNumber = formnum)).ToList();
```

The first thing is try to never call `ToList` extension method from a `DbSet`, that will load your entire table to memory, is really inefficient and more when you can filter your data on the server side.

Comment: The problem is, that this method is called a lot and it slows down to send back to the database each time,

Comment: Well, the truth is that I don't know your scenario, but I don't think is a good idea load, eg, 100 000 records  to filter later in memory, but anyways that depends on you ;). You can also  use `IEnumerable<TSource>.Where` extension method in your `ticketquery` list, which returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. The advantage of this method over `FindAll` is  that `Where` implements deferred execution, where it doesn't actually do the lookup over your data until you need it.